# Webpage is zoomed out a bit despite using meta tags

Tags: html, web, mobile

Despite using the following meta tag, my webpage seems to be zoomed out a bit. I can't for the life of me figure out what is going wrong.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
```

What I expect to see:

[image]

What I end up seeing:

[image]

This happens on both Android and iOS. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1" />, if it doesn't work, I think you should check your styles for `<html>` and `<body>`

Comment: Ah! I found the issue. Looks like I have a min-width of 465px. If I remove that, the page scales just fine. Thanks.